# Where do I customize the heading for the ModelAdmin view?

Tags: django

If I have a model with a camel case name like `DepartmentalSuperLeader`; the admin view for this model has the heading

```
Departmental super leader
```

I want to customize this name. What method should I override ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `verbose_name` in the `Meta` of the `model` its well [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) for eg:

```
class MyModel(Model):
      .....
      class Meta:
            db_table = u"mytabel"
            verbose_name = "My Custom Name"
```

This should show your model in the admin index page with the set `verbose_name`

Comment: don't forget verbose_name_plural!

Comment: oh yes, indeed `verbose_name_plural` right after `verbose_name` in the documentation. This will allow you to set proper plurals for your model name which would otherwise sound funny with the default `s` :P

Comment: `verbose_name_plural` is only necessary if appending 's' is not good enough to pluralize the name. You can use `verbose_name_plural` without `verbose_name` or `verbose_name` without `verbose_name_plural`.